# django-registration не отправляет email

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

django 1.10
python3

Ошибка:

```
504 Gateway Time-out

nginx/1.10.2
```

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
AUTH_USER_EMAIL_UNIQUE = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_mail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_pass'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = ''
```

При отправке на локальном сервере(через бэкенд консоли) - письмо уходит, при перемещении письма на сервер и изменении настроек(EMAIL_BACKEND) - вылезает данная ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

нужно было использовать

```
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```